# apache camel cxf - change soap:address location

Tags: web-services, apache-camel, cxf, jbossfuse

I need to expose soap service on jboss fuse server. What I am tring to do is replicate an existing developed soap service.

**Existing Browser URL:**
 http://ip:8027/Services/Interface/WebServices/TestService.serviceagent?wsdl

**Existing Endpoint URL:**
 http://ip:3456//Services/Interface/WebServices/Service.serviceagent/ChangeCustomerBasicEndpoint1

According to my understanding the above Browser URL can be accessed in browser and WSDL can be viewed.
 Similarly we can use this Browser URL in SOAP-UI to get the WSDL and the Endpoint URL is where the request is sent to - right ?

[image]

I am able to expose the soap service, by using following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
    xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 ">
    <cxf:cxfEndpoint
        address="http://ip:8027/Services/Interface/WebServices/TestService.serviceagent?wsdl"
        id="testEndpoint" serviceClass="pk.com.test.app.TestService">

        <cxf:properties>
            <entry key="publishedEndpointUrl" 
            value="http://ip:3456//Services/Interface/WebServices/Service.serviceagent/ChangeCustomerBasicEndpoint1"/>
        </cxf:properties>

    </cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

Every thing is working fine, to the point when I sent the request from SOAP-UI. I get connection refused
because my publishedEndpointUrl has different port and url.

Any help on how to handle this ?

Answer (score 1):

The publishedEndpointUrl will always override the cxf:cxfEndpoint address attribute.

And the wsdl address would be publishedEndpointUrl + "?wsdl"

Comment: Hi Freeman Fang, I also have noticed that.
Is there any way to achieve what I am trying to do ?